# Angular Custom Directive Css

Tags: angular, directive

I was having some problem when trying to create a custom directive in Angular. Here is my html code:

```
 <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">              
    <label [hidden]="!initservicesService.invoiceCurrencyLblVisible" for="">Invoice Currency</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="currencyCd" [hidden]="!initservicesService.invoiceCurrencyComboBoxVisible" [(ngModel)]="billProfileDO.currencyCd" id="" [disabled]="initservicesService.invoiceCurrencyComboBoxEnabled" [required]="initservicesService.invoiceCurrencyComboBoxCompulsory"                     (ngModelChange)="invoiceCurrencyComboBox_valueChanged($event)">
            <option *ngFor="let item of invoiceCurrencyList" value="{{item.cdValue}}">{{item.decodeValue}}</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Then, in my "required" directive class, I am trying to add "*" to the label for each of the required property:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[required]'
})
export class RequiredDirective {
    constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
        this.el = el;
    }
    // tslint:disable-next-line: use-life-cycle-interface
    ngOnInit() {
        this.formRequiredFunctions();
    }

    public formRequiredFunctions() {
        const that = this.el.nativeElement;
        console.log(that)
        const className: any = this.el.nativeElement.className;
        if (className === 'form-control') {
            $(that)
                .prev('label')
                .after('<span class="required"> *</span>');
            $(that)
                .prev('.form-tooltip')
                .prev('label')
                .after('<span class="required"> *</span>');
            $(that)
                .parent('.input-group')
                .prev('label')
                .after('<span class="required"> *</span>');
        } 
    }
}
```

However, the problem is, for those field with "required" and "hidden" property, the "*" is still showing whereby it is not supposed to show. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to add "*" to elements in the ````<select>```` dropdown or to the label "Invoice Currency"? Also using Angular with jquery is just asking for problems.

Comment: @nash11 Yeah I am trying to add the "*" to the label. Do you have any recommended way in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a custom directive for `required` as Angular has already got that covered (see [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/RequiredValidator)). Use that along with the `ngIf` 
directive (see [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)) to display the "*" on the label.

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <label [hidden]="!initservicesService.invoiceCurrencyLblVisible" for="currencyCd">
    Invoice Currency<span *ngIf="initservicesService.invoiceCurrencyComboBoxCompulsory"> *</span>
  </label>
  <select class="form-control" name="currencyCd" id="currencyCd"
    [hidden]="!initservicesService.invoiceCurrencyComboBoxVisible"
    [disabled]="initservicesService.invoiceCurrencyComboBoxEnabled"
    [required]="initservicesService.invoiceCurrencyComboBoxCompulsory"
    (ngModelChange)="invoiceCurrencyComboBox_valueChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="billProfileDO.currencyCd">
    <option *ngFor="let item of invoiceCurrencyList" value="{{item.cdValue}}">
      {{item.decodeValue}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```